# Launch two urdfs under same spawner giving issues with different descriptions

Tags: ros, roslaunch, urdf, ros-control, spawn-model

I'm trying to launch two robots (panda and iiwa) under the same urdf spawner node. Both robots have a different robot description that I pass to the node as a parameter. My issue is that for some reason, gazebo only wants to show me the iiwa robot so there is something wrong. I have checked the nodes and parameters in the terminal and seems to be ok.Am I missing something¿?

```
My main.launch
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<launch>

  <!-- Gazebo & GUI Configuration -->
  <arg name="debug" default="false"/>
  <arg name="gui" default="true"/>
  <arg name="paused" default="true"/>
  <arg name="world" default="$(find robot_ctrl)/world/worldTable.world"/>
  <arg name="controllers" default="joint_state_controller dual_cartesian_impedance_controller"/>
  <arg name="robot_name_right" default="panda" />
  <arg name="robot_name_left" default="iiwa" />
  <arg name="robot_state_frequency" default="100" />


  <!-- Robot Customization: PANDA -->
    <include file="$(find robot_ctrl)/launchDualControllers/launch_panda.launch">
      <arg name="x" value="0.6"/>
      <arg name="y" value="0"/>
      <arg name="z" value="0.5"/>
      <arg name="roll" value="0"/>
      <arg name="pitch" value="0"/>
      <arg name="yaw" value="3.1415"/>
      <arg name="paused" value="$(arg paused)"/>
      <arg name="arm_id_right" default="$(arg robot_name_right)" />
    </include>
  
  <!-- Robot Customization: iiwa -->
    <include file="$(find robot_ctrl)/launchDualControllers/launch_iiwa.launch">
      <arg name="origin_xyz" default="'-0.6 0 0.5'"/> 
      <arg name="origin_rpy" default="'0 0 0'"/>
      <arg name="arm_id_left" default="$(arg robot_name_left)" />
    </include> 

     <!-- Spawn both robots -->
    <node name="urdf_spawner" pkg="gazebo_ros" type="spawn_model" respawn="false" output="screen"
          args="-urdf -model panda -param panda_robot_description
                -urdf -model iiwa -param iiwa_robot_description"/>

   <!-- World launch -->
  <include file="$(find gazebo_ros)/launch/empty_world.launch">
    <arg name="world_name" value="$(arg world)"/>
    <arg name="debug" value="$(arg debug)"/>
    <arg name="paused" value="$(arg paused)"/>
    <arg name="gui" value="$(arg gui)"/>
    <arg name="use_sim_time" value="true"/>
    <arg name="headless"    default="false" />
  </include>

    <!-- Include the controller launch file 
    <include file="$(find robot_ctrl)/launchDualControllers/controllers.launch">
        <arg name="arm_id_right" default="$(arg robot_name_right)" />
        <arg name="arm_id_left" default="$(arg robot_name_left)" />
        <arg name="controllers" default="joint_state_controller dual_cartesian_impedance_controller"/>
     </include>-->
</launch>
```

my panda_launch is simple (I'm posting the launch part only):

```
<param name="panda_robot_description"
    command="xacro $(find franka_description)/robots/$(arg arm_id)/$(arg arm_id).urdf.xacro
            gazebo:=true
            hand:=$(arg use_gripper)
            arm_id:=$(arg arm_id)
            xyz:='$(arg x) $(arg y) $(arg z)'
            rpy:='$(arg roll) $(arg pitch) $(arg yaw)'
            $(arg xacro_args)">
</param>
```

my iiwa launch:

```
<!-- Load the URDF with the given hardware interface into the ROS Parameter Server -->
    <param name="iiwa_robot_description" command="$(find xacro)/xacro '$(find iiwa_description)/urdf/iiwa14.urdf.xacro' hardware_interface:=$(arg hardware_interface) robot_name:=$(arg robot_name_left)   origin_xyz:=$(arg origin_xyz) origin_rpy:=$(arg origin_rpy)"/>
```

my rosparam list shows /iiwa_robot_description and /panda_robot_description:

```
/arm_id
/franka_gripper/arm_id
/franka_gripper/finger1/gains/d
/franka_gripper/finger1/gains/i
/franka_gripper/finger1/gains/p
/franka_gripper/finger2/gains/d
/franka_gripper/finger2/gains/i
/franka_gripper/finger2/gains/p
/franka_gripper/type
/gazebo/auto_disable_bodies
/gazebo/cfm
/gazebo/contact_max_correcting_vel
/gazebo/contact_surface_layer
/gazebo/enable_ros_network
/gazebo/erp
/gazebo/gravity_x
/gazebo/gravity_y
/gazebo/gravity_z
/gazebo/max_contacts
/gazebo/max_update_rate
/gazebo/sor_pgs_iters
/gazebo/sor_pgs_precon_iters
/gazebo/sor_pgs_rms_error_tol
/gazebo/sor_pgs_w
/gazebo/time_step
/iiwa_robot_description
/m_ee
/panda_robot_description
/rosdistro
/roslaunch/uris/host_mikelpc__34387
/rosversion
/run_id
/singularity_warning_threshold
/tau_ext_lowpass_filter
/use_sim_time
```

my launch shows the node:

```
SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /arm_id: panda
 * /franka_gripper/arm_id: panda
 * /franka_gripper/finger1/gains/d: 1.0
 * /franka_gripper/finger1/gains/i: 0
 * /franka_gripper/finger1/gains/p: 100
 * /franka_gripper/finger2/gains/d: 1.0
 * /franka_gripper/finger2/gains/i: 0
 * /franka_gripper/finger2/gains/p: 100
 * /franka_gripper/type: franka_gazebo/Fra...
 * /gazebo/enable_ros_network: True
 * /iiwa_robot_description: <?xml version="1....
 * /m_ee: 0.76
 * /panda_robot_description: <?xml version="1....
 * /rosdistro: noetic
 * /rosversion: 1.16.0
 * /singularity_warning_threshold: 0.0001
 * /tau_ext_lowpass_filter: 1.0
 * /use_sim_time: True

NODES
  /
    gazebo (gazebo_ros/gzserver)
    gazebo_gui (gazebo_ros/gzclient)
    urdf_spawner (gazebo_ros/spawn_model)
```

but for some reason if I do a rosnode list is not showing anything but /gazebo and /rosout
I dont understand what I'm missing.

Answer (score 0):

Try to include the panda robot initial pose as an argument of the spawn node.

```
<node name="urdf_spawner" pkg="gazebo_ros" type="spawn_model" respawn="false" output="screen"
           args="-urdf -model panda -param panda_robot_description
                 -urdf -model iiwa -param iiwa_robot_description -x $(arg x) -y $(arg y) -z $(arg z) -Y $(arg yaw) -R $(arg roll) -P $(arg pitch)"/>
```

Place the initial pose the panda robot as an argument of the `urdf_spawner` node. Change that and see if it works.

Comment: I tried as you say but is not working, it seems that only loads the last robot (iiwa robot). I reorganized the code to be easier to analyze and follow:

Comment: Try to spawn both robots on separate nodes. Check as well the ```respawn``` flag.